# Set-builder notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I determine the size of the following set with set builder notation?

$$\{ \in \mathbb{Z}_+\mid 4<<5\}$$

I don't know where to start and what integer value is usable.

Comment: It looks as though it contains all integers strictly between 4 and 5.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what kinds of $x$'s satisfy $4 < x < 5$? Are any of them integers?

Comment: @almagest what are those integers?

Comment: @MikeShasaco I can't think of any.

Comment: @pjs36 wouldn't it be decimal values such as 4.1 to 4.9

Comment: And things like 4.0003 or 4.999982, but right: they have to be *more than* 4, **and** *less than* 5.

Comment: They also have to be positive *integers* (in $\mathbb{Z}^+$) so can there even be any with $4<x<5$?

Comment: @MikeShasaco But $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers. So we are also told that $x$ must be an integer.

Comment: @coffeemath i don't there can be one integer that positive that can fit in 4 < x < 5

Comment: @MikeShasaco I think you're right.

Comment: @almagest so x is the integer value so x is the answer?

Comment: The answer would be $0$ since the question was to find the *size* of the set, and set is empty.

Comment: @coffeemath oh that makes sense, i was overthinking the question

Answer (score 3):

In set builder notation $\{ \in \mathbb{Z}_+\mid 4<<5\}$ literally means "the set of positive integers $x$ such that $x$ is greater than $4$ and less than $5$." How many positive integers satisfy the conditions to be in the set?

The answer is zero.

There are no positive integers greater than 4 and less than 5.

Now please accept this answer if it answers your question.